# Does there exist an $n$ such that $3^n$ starts with $2019$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Does there exist a natural number $n$ such that the first four digits in the decimal representation of $3^n$ is $2019$?

I know to estimate the last few digits of any exponent by reducing modulo $10^k$, but how to obtain the first few digits? Note that computational tools are discouraged. Instead pure analysis must be used to arrive at the conclusion. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Possibly a hint: More generally, we can ask about the density of the image of $n \mapsto \{n\cdot \log_{10}(3)\}$ in $[0,1)$.  (Here, $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$)

Comment: @BrianMoehring sorry, what do you imply by 'density'

Comment: I think Brian means to ask if there's a value between any two given values

Comment: In short, there is an open set $(a,b) \subset [0,1)$ such that $a < \{n\cdot \log_{10}(3)\} < b$ for some $n$ implies $3^n$ begins with whatever string of digits you want, including $2019.$ There may be another tool to study the first however many digits, but the fractional part of the logarithm is the only one I know of.

Comment: @BrianMoehring so the answer is in the affirmative right? but proving the density is hard, I suppose, I think it uses the rational approximation to the irrational $\log_{10}3$ right?

Comment: The point is that $\log_{10}(3)$ is irrational, and the sequence of fractional parts of multiples of an irrational number is dense in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael so this implies if $\log_{10}a$ is irrational, then $a^n$ could start with any string of integers, right?

Comment: Yes, it does.  BTW, in this case $n=686$ works.

Comment: In fact, more is known: the sequence of fractional parts of multiples of an irrational number is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$, in the sense that the number of $n \in [0,N]$ where the fractional part is in $[a,b] \subseteq [0,1]$ is asymptotic to 
$(b-a)N$.  See [equidistribution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem)